# Javascript/Jquery get button text inside iframe

Tags: html, iframe, cross-domain

We have a simple HTML page where we are using an iframe to load a URL from a different domain.
We want to get the label of a button inside iFrame. And then change it to something else. How can we achieve that, please? Please note, we cannot change anything inside the URL which we are calling. we just have access to the HTML page where we are calling this page inside iFrame. Below is the button on the page that gets invoked via iframe.

```
<button type="submit" data-pp-button="test-button" tabindex="0" class="test-btn" ">Test</button>
```

We need to change the button text from "Test" to "Test 1". Is this even possible without changing anything inside the actual page in URL itself?

Comment: Impossible unless you have administrative privileges with the webpage inside the iframe.

Comment: That is the limitation, don't have access to the webpage inside the iframe!

Answer (score 0):

After investigating much on this issue, I understood that it's not possible to change the attributes of an iframe elements.

I found a strange workaround but might work for you - add a button with position absolute and place it above the iframe button, provide the same style and once user clicks on this button the covered button onClick will be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it right-away. But you can use your webserver as a proxy. Instead of loading the target URL in the `iframe` directly, you can have a page of your own which, on server-side would send a request to the URL that you consider to be your target and send the response to the browser. You could display this response in your `iframe` and then you will have the very same domain inside the `iframe` as in outside, so you will be able to find the elements in your `iframe` like described here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_element_iframe.asp